# How do i receive json string from Azure Function to save like json file in blob storage

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a flow on Power Automate. It will post a json-string to my azure function. How can i write this json to a json file in blobs storage using Azure Data Factory or only Azure Function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample where you can save JSON through the azure function.
For example, Considering this to be my workflow

[image]

I am using HTTP trigger in my case and sending the JSON sample to my function app which has output binding as blob storage and My Http function App looks like this:-

****init**.py**

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    print(str(req.get_json()))

    outputblob.set(str(req.get_json()))
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "outputcontainer/sample.json",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

**RESULT :**

**In power Automate**

[image]

**In function app**

[image]

**In Storage Account**

[image]